# How to use Qt5 and Qt Creator 2.6.1 with compiler from VS 2012?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, qt-creator, qt5

The official [downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads) only include Qt libraries 5.0.0 for VS 2010 now. I tried them in VS 2012 Express but got an error message as "error: LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1600' doesn't match value '1700'..."

Do I have to install VS 2010 or compile the entire source code of Qt5 in VS 2012?

**UPDATE:** My IDE is Qt Creator 2.6.1. I only use the C++ compiler in VS 2012 because there are no Qt libraries 5.0.0 for minGW in the official [downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads) yet.

**UPDATE-2(2013-1-1):** Saw it today, [the official blog](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/12/19/qt-5-0/) says:

> There are a few things we’re still working on for the 5.0 series. We
>   have bugs that we want to fix. We currently do not have binary
>   packages for MinGW (as WebKit doesn’t yet work with it yet) and MSVC
>   2012 (you’ll need to compile from source), and we’ll work on
>   delivering these as soon as possible. The current plan is to have a
>   first patch level release, 5.0.1, some time before the end of January.

**UPDATE-3(2013-1-31):** [That](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/01/31/qt-5-0-1-released/) comes finally, but only adds Qt 5.0.1 for MinGW 4.7.

**UPDATE-4(2013-7-06):** After a long wait, [Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2012, 511 MB)](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.1) added.

Comment: This is the problem - you are way faster than Qt team. Wait for some time if VC++2010 is not good enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right - if you want to use MS VC 2012 compiler, you have to compile QT5 libraries manually. The tutorial can be found on http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git. 
Another option is to install VS 2010 and use it until Digia will make pre-compiled VC 2012 and MinGW libraries. If you use QT Creator as your primary IDE, it should be enough to install VC 2010 Express only.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll do it when I have time. Hope Digia will do it before me :P

Answer (score 2):

What do you have set in **Visual Studio 2012**?

> Project properties > General > Platform toolset

Try setting it to `v110`.

More info at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx).

Comment: Do you mean that in the IDE VS 2012? Sorry, my words weren't clear. My IDE is Qt Creator 2.6.1. I only use the C++ compiler in VS 2012.